# curl terminal - POST request with Basic Authorization and body containing authorization code

Tags: ios, bash, curl, terminal, oauth-2.0

i have following params:

```
$url = "https://example.com/auth_token.json"
$clientId = "...", $secretId = "..."
$callback = "http://example"
$code = "1234" - # i've received if earlier, 

$body = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=$code&redirect_uri=$callback"
```

My goal is to get token with code, service says :

"Send a POST request to $url, providing the Client ID and Secret Key as HTTP Basic Authorization credentials, and a post body containing grant_type=authorization_code
and get in response json with token."

I tried something like this

```
curl $url --verbose -d $body -X -POST
```

but answer is - Status :401, nonauthorized and json "Unauthorized client or authentication failed, check your credentials."

then i tried to add

```
-H "Authorization : Basic ...encoded value..."
```

and get "Bad request"

Help me please, i missed something, 
thx

Comment: Did you literally use this? `-H "Authorization : Basic + encode64($clientId:$secretId)"` That won't work; neither bash nor curl will do the `encode64` for you.

Comment: of course not, i calculated it manualy and inserted

i also used -u user:pass, gives the same...

Comment: ok, just checking. You shouldn't actually need to tell curl to make it a POST request, but if you want to do that the invocation is `-X POST`, not `-X -POST`. `-d` implies a POST request, anyway, so it shouldn't be needed at all.

Comment: my god, removed "-X POST" and it works", thank you my saver

Comment: the mistake was in "-X -POST".... i hate myself, extra minus there..